# check for current post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have registered a custom post type and inisde my archive-myCPT.php I want to retrieve **just** the current published post.
Here is a relevant snippet from my archive-myCPT.php:

```
if( have_posts() ){ 

$x = 1;
while ( have_posts() ){
 the_post(); 
  if ( 0 === (int) $post->post_parent) {
   get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/content-debate');

 }
```

How can I add inside this loop a condition to check for the current published post and retrieve just one (the most recent one) ? Is this possible ? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can directly retrieve post filtering the choices in wp_query arguments

```
<?php 
// The Query
$args=array(
'post_type'=>'custom-post-type',
'posts_per_page'=>1,
'post_parent'=>'parent-page-id',
'order'=>'DESC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();?>

/*title*/    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
/*image*/    <?php the_post_thumbnail();  ?>

<?php }} 

wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

So there will be no need of filtering inside the loop.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop you get only published posts, so this is not your concern.

If you want the very last published post, add before `if(have_posts())` function `query_posts('posts_per_page=1&order=DESC&orderby=date&post_type=my_custom_post_type')`

Via [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) you can easily modify your loop.

**EDIT:**

To retrieve specifically one post rather than the loop use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

```
$posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=1&post_type=my_custom_post_type');

//do not use reserved variable name $post
foreach($posts as $single_post)  setup_postdata($single_post);
    //you can use the_title(), the_content()...
```

Comment: If I use this, will retrieve only the most recent published post ?

Comment: I've tried this but is not good for me, it retrieves the last post from the default blog posts not from my CPT and it adds also a pagination for other posts.

Comment: to retrieve CPT, add into query_posts argument `&post_type=my_custom_post_type`. I am not hundred percent sure, whether you can disable showing pagination links when using the loop, (except remove pagination code) you can try `&paged=0` or `&paged=1`. By all means, check my edit, I fond another solution that might be resourceful for you in this situation.

Comment: So where exactly I should add this ? before the `if( have_posts() ){ ` or inside the `while ( have_posts() ){`. I want to display the post, forget about retrieving just the thumbnail and the title.

Comment: You remove the whole loop starting from `if( have_posts...` up to `}`, what is basically the 'end of if' curly bracket, and replace it with code I provided (`get_posts...`). I assume that you are able to deal with the rest of foreach loop. In the end, if I write somehow unclear, or may I did not get your full intent, put your code of archive-cpt.php here.